# "TypeError: domNode is undefined" and other errors with Elm and 3rd party JS libraries

Tags: javascript, elm

I have been trying to use Elm applications to work with a handful of "UI Widget" type libraries. In particular I have been working with highlight.js and CodeMirror.

[This](https://ryanucode.github.io/elm-editor-demo/index.html) is a set of pared down code snippets from the project. The "Simple" example is just the raw elm app with no 3rd party libraries to show the expected result of the application. "Highligh JS" is a version showing errors working with the highlight.js library. Finally "CodeMirror" shows issues working with the CodeMirror library.

The source code for the above examples can be found [here](https://github.com/ryanucode/elm-editor-demo). The pertinent files are /src/*.elm and docs/*.html

The CodeMirror example gives the error from the title while the Highlight JS example results in a "corrupted" DOM.

Many 3rd party JS libraries modify the DOM. How do you work with those libraries cleanly in Elm?

Comment: I have addressed this matter in an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40580380/2294657) to a similar question. Check it out, it explains core concepts of integrating Elm with any other JavaScript technology.